# On click, passing a variable from Javascript into Rails/Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I have a Javascript Highchart that I'm displaying and trying to get more information out of. I have it set up currently so when I click a column in the bar graph, it alerts me to the name of the column and the value.

I'm trying to go a step further by rendering the contents of that column of the graph in a table below. I have the HTML all done but I'm trying to pass in the value clicked, `this.category` which contains a string, into the @show_me instance variable that will render the chart as soon as it's not nil.

My code below is breaking my graph, causing it not to render. I'm not entirely sure of the correct way to pass in the value of `this.category` into @show_me on click.

Any help would be huge. Thanks so much!

> click: function() { this.category == <%= @show_me %>; }

Comment: `==` is an equality check, not an assignment. Go read up on operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it appears like you just need to change this

```
this.category == <%= @show_me %>;
```

to this

```
this.category = "<%= @show_me %>";
```

Although you should be aware that anything with the `<%= %>` tags is prerendered before the page is loaded.

**Update:**

Looks like what you're trying to do might involve some AJAX. You might consider looking through [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/) since this is a semi-complicated topic, and can be confusing if you have no experience with it.

Comment: Gotcha. So now that the graph loads but as you mention, the table is pre-loaded so the value clicked isn't able to be rendered in the table. How do I make it render?

Comment: @ZackShapiro I'm still really unclear on what you're trying to do. I suggest you revise your question -- what functionality are you trying to accomplish? This should be from the highest level possible, in other words 'I am trying to get this button to show a column on click'.

Comment: I am trying to get a table to render with the contents of a column of the bar graph when a user clicks on a certain bar. To do that, I need to pass `this.category` into either an instance variable or into a controller, I believe.